# Bounds of the integrals when calculating $P(X+g(Z) \geqslant t, Z \geqslant a,X < t)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Y$ be a function of $Z$, i.e. $Y=g(Z)$, where function $g(Z)$ increases with $Z$, with $g(Z=0)=0$ and $g(Z \rightarrow \infty)=c$; $c$ is a positive constant. $Z$ and $X$ are independent (positive) random variables.  Let $f_X(x)$ and $f_Z(z)$ be the PDFs of $X$ and $Z$, respectively.

My goal is to find the probability of having: $(X+Y \ge t)$, $(Z \ge a)$, and $(X < t)$, i.e.
$P(X+Y \ge t, Z \ge a,X < t)$, where $a$ and $t$ are positive constants.

To this end, I am using: $\int\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx=\int\int f_{X}(x) f_Y(y) dydx$.

My question is about the bounds of the integrals: 
I know that if we (only) have $X+Y \le t$, the bounds are as follows: $X \in [0,t)$ and $Y \in [0,t-x)$; btw, is it correct ?   How to choose these bounds when $X+Y \ge t$ (in addition to the other conditions given before, i.e.  $Z \ge a,X < t$ )?

Comment: $$P(X+g(Z) \geqslant t, Z \geqslant a,X < t)=\int_0^tP(g(Z)\geqslant t-x,Z\geqslant a)f_X(x)dx$$ $$P(g(Z)\geqslant t-x,Z\geqslant a)=1-F_Z(\max\{a,g^{-1}(t-x)\})$$

Comment: @Did So I think what remains is to check whether $a \ge g^{-1}(t-x)$ over the interval $x \in [0,t]$. Anw, thank you for your generous comment! Please note that in case you want to write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.